# Android font rendering, i am getting very bad view

Tags: android, fonts, font-face, genymotion

I am using arial.ttf in my project. In genymotion emulator,in some mobile devices my text view is look good. But in Sony Xperia tablet 4.1.1 i have a text rendering problem. Text looking very  bad. What should i do?

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/yazi1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Ret"
    android:textColor="@color/siyah"
    android:textColorHint="@color/siyah"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font14" />

Typeface tfArial = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "arial_tur2.ttf")
```

screenshot http://hizliresim.com/ynJjWk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use OTF instead of TTF. That can be your problem. I was in this situation and changing the file with OTF solved my problem.

OTF is more likely to be a “better” font, as it supports more advanced typesetting features (smallcaps, alternates, ligatures and so on actually inside the font rather than in fiddly separate expert set fonts). It can also contain either spline (TTF-style) or Bezier (PostScript Type 1-style) curves, so hopefully you're getting the shapes the font was originally designed in and not a potentially-poorer-quality conversion.

On the other hand, if you're downloading free fonts from shovelware sites, you're unlikely to get any of that. Indeed, you may simple be getting a TTF font renamed to OTF.